# Reversing a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a script that clones the last table row and inserts it at the bottom of my table by clicking a [+] icon. What I'd like to do is allow the removal of the last table row by clicking an [-] icon. Is this possible and if so, could someone point me in the right direction?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #itemid').val('');
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #itemdesc').val('');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that sarcasm exists on a site like this where people are supposed to help each other.

Comment: Actually it's fine...http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5314/217110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jQuery has a function called [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$("#remove").click(function(e) {
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').remove();
        e.preventDefault(); // dont use return false, use preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[Here you can find some info why you should not user `return false;` unless you know what you are doing](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)

You could make it a bit more faster

```
$("#remove").click(function(e) {
        $('#mytable tbody tr').filter(':last').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: The `tbody` is not needed if there's only `tbody`s... otherwise the last row of a `thead` will also be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method is what you're looking for:

```
$("#remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mytable > tbody > tr:last-child').remove();
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` is to prevent the default action of the element (whether it's a button or a link). I'm assuming that there is a default action, since you're using `return false;` in the original add code.

(Side note: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false))

Also, I'm using `:last-child` here instead of `:last` [for better performance](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

> Because `:last` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:last` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:last` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":last")`.

Since the pure CSS selector works in this case (assuming you have a well-formed table), there is no need to `.filter(':last')`. You should also be able to do this in your `#add` code when cloning the last row.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$("#remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').remove();
});
```